# Not responding while compiling this function?

Tags: delphi, compilation, delphi-xe

I tried with Delphi XE and I got Not Responding while compiling. Does it work in your computer or is there something wrong with the function?

```
function Test(const FileName: string;
  const Force: boolean = false): boolean;
var
  IsAllowed: boolean;
begin
  result := false;
  if FileExists(FileName) then
  begin
    try
      if (Force) then
      begin
        result := false;
        exit;
      end;
    finally
      if IsAllowed then
        DeleteFile(FileName);
    end;

    try
      result := true;
    except
      result := false;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That function compiles fine in my Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It compiles on my computer. Though I get the warning W1036 Variable 'IsAllowed' might not have been initialized.

Update: I can reproduce the hang when I include Windows in the uses clause.
**Subbmitted to Quality Central: [QC93806](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=93806).**

```
program hang_test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  // Windows, // uncomment to include Windows -> hang on compile
  SysUtils;

function Test(const FileName: string; const Force: boolean = false): boolean;
  // your function here

begin
  try

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

It looks like a bug; you should report it in the [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/).

Update 2: Minimal case which reproducibly hangs the compiler:

```
function HangCompiler: Boolean;
begin
  try
    Exit; // 1. exit from a try..finally
  finally
    DeleteFile(''); // 2. inlined function call in finally (include Windows to inline)
  end;
  // 3. try..except
  try
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yeah, I think there's a chance it *might* not have been initialized too!

Comment: I can compile it if I comment out `DeleteFile(FileName);` or `result := true;`. What is the version of your Delphi XE?

Comment: Yes, Windows in the uses clause is the trouble maker. I just try to comment out `Windows` and I can compile the function.

Comment: Delphi XE 15.0.3953.3571 with Update 1 and Help Update 2. BTW, command line compiler hangs, too.

Comment: You can presumably work around it by declaring your own version of DeleteFile which isn't inlined?

Comment: @David Yes, probably; the inlined call seems to be required to reproduce the hang.